# Using array from class in main function

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    class treasure
    {
    public:
        char name[100];
        double value[100];
        double weight[100];
    };

    int itemNumber, totalWeight, i;

    treasure item;

    std::cout << "Enter total item weight: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> totalWeight;
    std::cout << "Enter total item number: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> itemNumber;
    for( i = 0; i < itemNumber; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter item name: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> item.name[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to input 5 item in the array but it is just asking for two item. It takes one item at first and then after printing three lines again takes another input. What seems to be the problem. What did went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char name[100];` means that you can save up to 100 items of type `char`, not 100 strings.

An important effect here is that your input is buffered. `std::cin >> item.name[i];` takes one `char` from the input buffer and writes it to `name[i]`. The rest of your input remains in the buffer and will be used for the next execution of `cin`, i.e. the next execution of the same code line.

So if you enter e.g. 'abc' it saves 'a' to `item.name[0]`, 'b' to `item.name[1]` and 'c' to `item.name[2]`. For `item.name[3]` the input buffer is empty so it waits for your next input.